# How to set MySQL Events to not trigger if last event is still executing

Tags: mysql

I normally set MySql Events as follows, where UpdateTable() is a stored procedure which changes the table data.

```
CREATE EVENT UpdateTable_Every1Mins -- Create and Event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
DO CALL UpdateTable();
```

Occasionally, the UpdateTable procedure is time consuming and can span up to 3 minutes.  Since I've set the interval to 1 minute (as shown in the query above), how do I ensure that a new UpdateTable call is not triggerred when the current UpdateTable call is still running?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, directly.

Indirectly, sure.

Inside the procedure, before any other work:

```
IF GET_LOCK('my_lock_name',0) IS NOT TRUE THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'failed to obtain lock; not continuing';
END IF;
```

Right before the end of the procedure:

```
DO RELEASE_LOCK('my_lock_name');
```

This is a named lock.  It doesn't lock rows or tables, it just locks the name `'my_lock_name'` (a name you make up) in a global memory structure so that no other thread can lock the same name.  The `0` means not to wait around for the lock but to immediately return false (0) if someone else holds the lock or null if an error occurs -- and `IS NOT TRUE` matches either null or 0.  See [`GET_LOCK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) in the manual.  The above code works in MySQL Server 5.5 or later.  Earlier versions support the locks, but do not support `SIGNAL` to halt execution.

Releasing the lock is not technically necessary with events, since it's released when the client thread terminates, and each event invocation is in its own thread, which terminates when the event invocation ends... but it's best practice.

`SIGNAL` throws an exception, which stops execution of the procedure and of this invocation of the event.  The message_text is logged to the MySQL error log.